# :focus rules are not applied

Tags: html, css, pseudo-class

I'm trying to apply different styles to an element when it's focused, using the `:focus` pseudoclass. At a very basic level, I have something like this:

```css
input {
  border: 1px solid red;
}

input:focus {
  border: 1px solid blue;
}
```

```html
<input type="text">
```

I expected the border of the input field to become blue when it's focused (clicked), but it becomes black instead. Why is that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is being applied by your brower. Google Chrome's default user agent stylesheet (and probably other browsers) has the following rule

```css
:focus-visible {
  outline: -webkit-focus-ring-color auto 1px;
}
```

Therefore, you'll need to override this rule too, e.g.

```css
input:focus-visible {
  outline: unset;
}
```

```css
input:focus {
  border-color: red;
}

input:focus-visible {
  outline: unset;
}
```

```html
<input />
```

Comment: I'm using Chrome indeed. I set the `outline` to `none` and it worked. Thank you!